# Condition of wall stud

Tags: framing

I am giving my best shot at remodeling a kitchen. I don’t have too much experience with framing, as the bathroom I remodeled was done with the assistance of an experienced contractor who knew when to sister studs, etc.

There are several studs in the load bearing wall that have small chunks missing (see picture), or knots that have since fallen out.

Do these studs need to be replaced or sistered, or are they just fine the way they are?

[image]

Comment: Personally, I'd be more concerned about splitting than edge bits missing.  Knots...only if they're pretty big.  There are guidelines for how much wood can be missing before load-bearing capacity is lost, but I'll leave that info to the pros.